# Convert an SQL query with row_number to AR code

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have somewhat complex SQL query that I need to convert to nice and clean AR code, and I'm having some troubles with it.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
  fixed_assets a
  INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT e.id, e.fixed_asset_id
      FROM
        fixed_asset_book_entries e
      WHERE e.book_id = %SOME_VALUE_1%
    ) e_mod
    ON e_mod.fixed_asset_id = a.id
  INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT s.fixed_asset_book_entry_id,
             s.status,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.fixed_asset_book_entry_id ORDER BY s.created_at DESC) AS rn
      FROM
        status_changes s
      WHERE s.created_at < %SOME_VALUE_2%
    ) s_mod
    ON s_mod.fixed_asset_book_entry_id = e_mod.id AND s_mod.rn = 1 AND s_mod.status <> 'inactive'
ORDER BY a.id;
```

So, the point of it all is to extract such `fixed_assets` rows, that have related `fixed_asset_book_entries` with certain `book_id`, and it's last `status_change` before certain date has any status except `inactive`.

What I want to end up with is a class-level (scope?) method `FixedAsset.active_within_book_on_date(book_id, date)`, that will return FixedAsset objects, that comply with restrictions I've explained above. I'm familiar with `joins` method, but I'm not sure how to handle `row_number` function except passing raw SQL to `joins` call.

Comment: I believe the SQL methods you are using are non-standard, and therefore it is not possible, without patching AR, to use them in a Rails way as 'nice and clean AR code'. AR / Arel abstracts the SQL `standard`, but does not attempt to implement or use non-standard functionality from a particular DBMS. It seems `ROW_NUMBER` and the `OVER` clause with `PARTITION` is sql-server only. Depending on your definition of 'nice and clean', you won't find a way to do this. However, you can certainly build a class method and use the SQL above.

Comment: @Midwire Window functions certainly are standard and have been supported in PostgreSQL for years. The problem is that ActiveRecord only understands baby-talk SQL and AREL is pretty much unusable for building a query by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am certainly no DBA or SQL expert and had not run across a need for those functions before. It seems that everyone's favorite toy DB, MySQL, does not support those functions. And since AR/Arel needs to be DBMS agnostic, I can see why it doesn't go there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best you can do is something like the following. In `lib/sql_template.rb`:

```
class SqlTemplate
  attr_reader :sql
  # Load the file and process the ERB
  # Call it like this:
  #   sql = SqlTemplate.new(filename, binding)
  def initialize(filename, the_binding)
    raw_code = File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'lib/sql', filename))
    template = ERB.new(raw_code)
    @sql     = template.result(the_binding)
  end
end
```

Then define your raw SQL in `lib/sql/active_within_book_on_date.sql`. Which would then allow you to do this:

```
class FixedAsset
  def self.active_within_book_on_date(book_id, date)
    template = SqlTemplate.new('active_within_book_on_date.sql', binding)
    self.find_by_sql(template.sql)
  end
end
```

Your SQL file would look like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
  fixed_assets a
  INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT e.id, e.fixed_asset_id
      FROM
        fixed_asset_book_entries e
      WHERE e.book_id = <%=book_id%>
    ) e_mod
    ON e_mod.fixed_asset_id = a.id
  INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT s.fixed_asset_book_entry_id,
             s.status,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.fixed_asset_book_entry_id ORDER BY s.created_at DESC) AS rn
      FROM
        status_changes s
      WHERE s.created_at < '<%=date%>'
    ) s_mod
    ON s_mod.fixed_asset_book_entry_id = e_mod.id AND s_mod.rn = 1 AND s_mod.status <> 'inactive'
ORDER BY a.id;
```

That's probably as 'nice and clean' as you can get.